# Make Image Spin Until Stopped - Xcode Mac App

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a png of a gear the I want to react just like an NSProgressIndicator, so that when a process is happening, it spins, and when nothing is happening, it stops. I am new to Xcode stuff, so sorry if I get terms wrong or just look stupid... This is a mac app so I am guessing it is different then iOS app development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a recently written guide to doing **[exactly what you want to do](http://chamelo.co.uk/spin-it)**

Let me know if you need some of it explained!

Comment: And you should probably put objective-c and ios in your tags instead of c++, spin and image. Please accept the answer, if you can use it.

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I wanted, thanks! Sorry about the tags, I was tired and like I said, a noob. Thanks again!!!!!